# python setup.py install/develop does not reinstall everything

Tags: python, package

I have come across one very mysterious situations that has struggled me for quite long. Let's make thing simple in this way:

I have a python package, including these 3 files(I only mentioned those related here):

```
folder1/setup.py
folder1/scripts/csce.py
folder1/bregman/ceset.py
```

folder1/scripts/csce.py
contains a line:

```
from bregman.casm import CASMSet
```

I have a few versions of such package with different modificaion of my own. OK, in my Mac in folder1, I previously python setup.py develop one version, after I copy such package to folder2 and modify both folder2/scripts/csce.py and folder2/bregman/ceset.py . Then I python setup.py develop again, everything works great.

However, previously I also setup folder1/setup.py in my cluster. After I copy my code folder2 to my cluster and peform python setup develop, it seems in my PATH/bin/csce.py, it refers to folder2/scripts/csce.py, this is nice and good. However, the bregman function it calls refers to the previously installed folder1/bregman/ceset.py . I have to go to the site-packages folder and remove something like breggman.egg . and perform python setup develop in folder 2 to make everything work again... Does anyone know why do i need to remove that bregman.egg in order to python setup.py develop the latest code? Thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you have and what you do from your explanation. Please improve it to [mcve] quality.

Comment: More specifically: 1) "I have a few versions of such package" - what is the setup before the steps that follow? Is any of the packages installed? 2)..."everything works great" - do you happen to run `python` from the same directory where your modified files are, or it works from anywhere? 3) "I also setup folder1/setup.py in my cluster" - what kind of "cluster" that is? Specifically, what happens at cluster level when you run `setup.py` (if it's not something standard for that cluster implementation)? ...

Comment: ... 4)same as 1), what is the setup for the "cluster" before the steps that follow? 5)"it seems in my PATH/bin/csce.py" - please state the facts that make you think so rather than just your opinion, as it may be wrong and tells us nothing about what actually goes on there. Also, what's "PATH" here and why "/bin/csce.py" follows rather than just `csce.py` or something? 6) The same as 5) goes for the alleged "<file > references <some other file>" - what facts make you think so?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Most confusing question I have ever read on this site :)

Comment: did you delete all `.pyc` files ? @mertyildiran touch right point.

Comment: @dsgdfg, delete them from where?

Comment: do 'find <path-to>/folder[12] -name "*.pyc"'. Those ones. Also you might need to 'find <path-to>/folder[12] -name "\_\_pycache\_\_"' and delete those directories.